# maven Jarに特定のライブラリを含めたくない

Tags: java, kotlin, maven, intellij-idea

IntelliJで2つのモジュールを使用したプロジェクトを作っています。
この内、片方のモジュール（自分でプロジェクトに追加した外部モジュール）は
`jar`として書き出すときに中に含めたくありません。
実行時にクラスパスとして指定したいからです。
なので

```
<!-- プロジェクトに追加した外部モジュール -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aaa</groupId>
    <artifactId>bbb</artifactId>
    <version>1.01</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

という風に追加したモジュールを`provided`を指定しました。
これにより開発時はクラスパスが通ってエラーが出ないで開発できます。
ですが、mavenで`jar`を書き出そうとするとたくさんの`Unresolved reference:`エラーが発生してコンパイルに失敗します。

開発時にクラスパスを通して、Jar発行時にはその中に含めたくない場合どうすればいいでしょうか？
`jar`の書き出しは`org.apache.maven.plugins`を使用しています。

### 参考余談

モジュールは`Project Structure`->`Project Settings`->`Modules`に追加しました。
それだけでは開発時もクラスが存在しないなどのエラーとなったため
IntelliJが表示したFixヒントを実行し、
`pom.xml`に↑で記載したモジュールが追加されました。
これにより開発時は追加したモジュールを正常に参照できるようになりました。

### pom.xml全文

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.aaa.bbb</groupId>
    <artifactId>ccc</artifactId>
    <version>1.00</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <kotlin.version>1.6.20</kotlin.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>company</id>
            <url>file:///xxxxxxxxxxxxx</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aaa</groupId>
            <artifactId>bbb</artifactId>
            <version>1.01</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Replacing default-compile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Replacing default-testCompile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- jarに依存関係（ライブラリ）を含めるのに使用する -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.aaa.bbb.ccc.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <!-- カーネル（アップデート対象のJAR） -->
                            <Class-Path>./aaa.jar</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`jar`書き出し時は`package`を実行。

Comment: 質問文の情報からは断定できませんが、 [KTIJ-19628](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19628) と同じ事象かもしれません。残念ながら特にworkaroundなどは記載されていないようです。

Comment: それっぽい気がしますね...
んー何とかならないものか。mavenの何かの機能で除外もしくはjarを一旦分解してもう一度組み立て...

Comment: scopeにcompileを指定しても同じエラーになってました。マルチモジュールの時のpom.xmlの設定を私が間違えているのかもしれないです。